# Is it reasonable to declare an exception type for a single function?

Tags: python, exception

Say I have this code:

```
def wait_for_x(timeout_at=None):
    while condition_that_could_raise_exceptions
        if timeout_at is not None and time.time() > timeout_at:
            raise SOMEEXCEPTIONHERE

        do_some_stuff()

try:
    foo()
    wait_for_x(timeout_at=time.time() + 10)
    bar()
except SOMEEXCEPTIONHERE:
    # report timeout, move on to something else
```

How do I pick an exception type `SOMEEXCEPTIONHERE` for the function? Is it reasonable to create a unique exception type for that function, so that there's no danger of `condition_that_could_raise_exceptions` raising the same exception type?

```
wait_for_x.Timeout = type('Timeout', (Exception,), {})
```

Comment: In Python 3.3, you could use the built-in `TimeoutError`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should certainly define your own exception class whenever none of the built-in exception types are appropriate. In some cases (say, if you're building some kind of HTML munger on top of LXML or BeautifulSoup) it might also be appropriate to use an exception from some other module.

Answer (score 1):

If distinguishing exceptions from `wait_for_x` from those from `condition_that_could_raise_exceptions` is important enough, then sure, define a new exception type. After all, the type is the main way of distinguishing different kinds of exceptions, and parsing the message tends to get messy pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Python Standard Library defines a lot of its own custom exceptions. It seems good practice to do that as well for personal modules or functions.